# Custom legend in a plot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, legend, legend-properties

I have a code which I draw a circle of given radius and color on some points of the graph. The following code is only a dummy example to illustrate how my code looks like. I also did use of some special cross markers. How should I make legend for this circles and crosses?
My legend should only represnt each circle by its color and a given radius in legend box and the same for the cross.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
circle1=plt.Circle((2,3),.1,color='r')
circle2=plt.Circle((6,2),.2,color='b')
circle3=plt.Circle((5,6),.34,color='b')
circle4=plt.Circle((5,2),.2,color='b')
circle5=plt.Circle((10,10),.3,color='g')
circle6=plt.Circle((12,15),.5,color='g')
circle7=plt.Circle((8,1),.4,color='g')
fig = plt.gcf()
markerSize=400;
fig.gca().scatter([4,6],[8,10],marker='+',s=markerSize)
fig.gca().add_artist(circle1)
fig.gca().add_artist(circle2)
fig.gca().add_artist(circle3)
fig.gca().add_artist(circle4)
fig.gca().add_artist(circle5)
fig.gca().add_artist(circle6)
fig.gca().add_artist(circle7)

#fig.savefig('plotcircles.png')
fig.gca().set_xlim(0,20)
fig.gca().set_ylim(0,20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: See this page: http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist

Comment: @tcaswell, what about changing their shape? Is that possible?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I think proxy artists will do everything you want.  If you can't get them to work, edit your question with what you have tried.